# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом И?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом И в таком предложении: "Мне не сложно совмещать службу с творчеством и никогда не было"?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится: Мне **не сложно совмещать** службу с творчеством,  и никогда **не было** (сложно совмещать).

Это **сложносочиненное предложение**, две предиктивные основы, оба предложения односоставные безличные, второе предложение неполное.

**Сказуемое составное глагольное** - "не сложно совмещать", модальная связка выражена предикативным наречием (не сложно), причем во втором предложении добавлена глагольная связка  "не было" для выражения формы прошедшего времени.

Comment: "Мне" является общим для двух предложений. Почему это не отменяет запятую?

Comment: Эти два предложения сложно объединить в одну фразу. Во-первых, здесь разные временные планы, во-вторых,  предложения разделяет наречие, отнесенное ко второму предложению. Кроме того, союз И  в данной конструкции может рассматриваться как присоединительный. Сравнить: Мне не сложно и не было никогда сложно совмещать службу с творчеством. Здесь мы действительно имеем одну фразу, объединенную  соединительным союзом И и общим дополнением.

Comment: >> *Кроме того, союз И в данной конструкции может рассматриваться как присоединительный*.   Не "кроме того", @Sibylla, а это единственное объяснение запятой. А вы, как всегда, растекаетесь мыслью по древу. Иначе говоря, умствуете на пустом месте. Разные временные планы, разделяет наречие... обалдеть. Да ещё и "сложносочиненное предложение". ))